# How to iterate over different URLs when fetching data?

Tags: javascript, json, asynchronous, web-scraping, axios

I updated the code with the help from some commenters. A short summary:
- I want to scrape the HTML with info about products from 800+ pages, and parse that data to JSON and save it in a JSON file. The code works when I do like 20 pages at a time, but when I try to do all of them, I get the following error:

```
Error: Max redirects exceeded.
```

This is the entire code:

```
// Import required modules
const axios = require('axios');
const cheerio = require('cheerio');
const fs = require('fs');

const url = "http://johndevisser.marktplaza.nl/?p=";

async function getProductsHtml(data) {
    const $ = await cheerio.load(data);
    let productsHTML = [];
    $("div.item").each((i, prod) => {
        productsHTML.push(($(prod).html()));
    });
    return productsHTML;
};

async function parseProducts(html) {
  let products = [];
  for (item in html) {
    // Store the data we already have
    const $ = await cheerio.load(html[item]);
    let product = {};
    let mpUrl = $("a").attr("href");
    product["title"] = $("a").attr("title");
    product["mpUrl"] = mpUrl;
    product["imgUrl"] = $("img").attr("src");
    let priceText = $("span.subtext").text().split("\xa0")[1].replace(",", ".");
    product["price"] = parseFloat(priceText);
    products.push(product);
  }
  return products;
}

async function addDescriptionToProducts(prods) {
  for (i in prods) {
    const response = await axios.get(prods[i]["mpUrl"])
    const $ = cheerio.load(response.data);
    description = $("div.description p").text();
    prods[i]["descr"] = description;
  }
  return prods
}

async function getProductsFromPage(i) {
  try {
      const page = await axios.get(`http://johndevisser.marktplaza.nl/?p=${i}`);
      console.log("GET request succeeded!");
      // Get the Array with HTML of each product
      const productsHTML = await getProductsHtml(page.data);
      console.log("HTML array obtained!");
      // Get the Array of objects with meta info
      const productsParsed = await parseProducts(productsHTML);
      console.log("Products parsed!")
      // Add description to each product
      const productsMeta = await addDescriptionToProducts(productsParsed);
      console.log("Descriptions added!")
      // Return the Array with all product information
      return productsMeta;
    } catch(e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
};

async function saveAllProducts() {
  try {
    const allProducts = await getAllProducts();
    let jsonProducts = await JSON.stringify(allProducts);
        fs.writeFile("products.json", jsonProducts, "utf8", (e) => {
          if (e) {
            console.log(e)
          }
        });
  } catch(e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
}

async function getAllProducts() {
  try {
    let allProducts = [];
    for (let i = 1; i < 855; i++) {
      const productsFromPage = await getProductsFromPage(i);
      allProducts = [...allProducts, ...productsFromPage];
      console.log("Saved products from page " + i);
    }
    return allProducts
  } catch(e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
}

saveAllProducts();
```

Comment: show your code, how your are iterating?

Comment: As mentioned, I'm not at the moment as the two things I tried didn't work. How do you recommend I'd iterate over all the different URLs?

Comment: `async function fetchAndUpdateProducts(pageNumber) {...}` and you loop somewhere else `for (let i=0; i<800; i++) { fetchAndUpdateProducts(i); }`

Comment: That wouldn't work, as I would get the data in different JSON files instead of all combined in one.

Comment: well `fs.appendFile` is not evil :)

Comment: Can you expand on that? I added the full code, note that I'm already writing files and adding a for loop around it would give me 800+ separate files. There must be a better way where I concatenate the JSON and then write it all to a single file, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before trying to get all 800 products I would highly recommend to take a step back and have a look at your current code. There are a few things which make it harder to run this script 800 times.

1. `getProducts` receives the page html and puts the html of the products in a global variable. This is called a **side effect** which makes the code more complicated than it needs to be.
2. `parseProducts` receives the array of product html but doesn't use it. Instead it is using the global variable.
3. `parseProducts` parses each product html and puts the meta data in yet another global variable.
4. `fetchAndUpdateProducts` is doing 2 things; parsing a page and writing to json

Because of these things the flow in `fetchAndUpdateProducts` becomes a bit unclear and debugging becomes hard.

So what I would recommend is start with a new method which is something like this

```js
async getProductsFromPage(i) {
  try {
      const page = await axios.get(`http://johndevisser.marktplaza.nl/?p=${i}`);
      
      // Get the Array with HTML of each product
      const productsHTML = getProductsHtml(response.data);
      
      // Get the Array of objects with meta info
      const productsParsed = parseProducts(productsHTML);
      
      // Add description to each product
      const productsMeta = await addDescriptionToProducts(productsParsed);

      // Return the Array with all product information
      return productsMeta;
    } catch(e) {

    }
}
```

After that you will be able to do something like this:

```js
const p1 = await getProductsFromPage(1);
const p2 = await getProductsFromPage(2);
const p3 = await getProductsFromPage(3);
// etc.
```

And even combine all data in a single array:

```js
let allProducts = [];

for(let i = 0; i < 800; i++){
  const productsFromPage = await getProductsFromPage(i);
  allProducts = [...allProducts, ...productsFromPage];
}

// Write to JSON
```

Comment: I made huge progress with this, thanks! Except, now I get an error saying "max redirects exceeded. I'll update the code.

Comment: I found the issue, apparently one of the products had only Greek characters in the title and that somehow blocked the whole page. The product page on the site was not accessible, but this was helped by adding "Greek music" to the product title. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can get all data and iterate.

Let's say, you have pages from 1 - 800

```js
const pageCount = 800;
const promises = [];
for (let page = 0; page < pageCount; page++) {
  promises.push(axios.get(`https://someurl?page=${page}`));
}

Promises.all(promises).then(responses => {
  // responses will be list of reaponse for each page in order
  // So now manipulate this data accordingly and write in your file here/
  
  const data = responses.flat();
});
```

Comment: Is this not gonna clash with the existing try/catch and async/await?

Comment: I edited the post to show the entire code, hope that helps!